# Powershell how to remove redundency in a n arraylist

Tags: powershell

I have the global arraylist "$global:processid", which has many processid-entries and $globale:processname, which has all the processes that belongs to the ids. sometimes all the entries the $global:processid arraylist got, are the same. how can i loop through the two arraylists and delete all duplicated processids and there processnames.  I got the following code now. But i don't have this filtering.
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$global:processname = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$global:processid = @()

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $global:processid.Count; $i++) {
         "Position "+$i+": "+$global:processid[$i]
         #$lvi = [System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]::new()
         #$lvi.Text = $global:processname[$i]
         #$lvi.SubItems.Add($global:processid[$i])
         #$global:ListviewOCLRA.Items.Add($lvi)
}
```

It is important that the it will be checked for duplicated processids and delete the processnae at this position. For instance
if the positions 3-7 are the same entries again and again in the $global:processid arraylist, all the entries at positions 3-7 in the arraylist $global:processname should also be deleted.

I hope u understand what i mean. Thx for the help.

Comment: The better solution would likely be to manage 1 list consisting of objects that have both the ID and Name together, this way you only need to prune once. Can you show us how you're populating these 2 lists in the first place?

Comment: Isn't this the same as I've answered in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70393515/9898643)? Especially the last part of my answer there shows how to get **one** array containing **objects** that have multiple properties that belong to each other. Using separate arrays really is to be avoided as there is nothing to match the values other that the array index..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although as commented, it would be best to use one single array containing **objects**, you can still create such an array using your two arraylists, *as long as they are still intact and where each index can get you the id and a matching process name*

Assume your arrays are like this:

```
$processid   = 123, 456, 123
$processname = 'notepad', 'powershell', 'notepad'
```

As you can see, there's a duplicate in there

Join these arrays while their indices still match the name and id into one single array of **objects**

```
$processes = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $processid.Count; $i++) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{ Id = $processid[$i]; Name = $processname[$i] }
}
```

Now you can eliminate the duplicate objects based on the ID property

```
$processes | Sort-Object -Property Id -Unique
```

`$processes` now contains:

```
 ID Name
 -- ----
123 notepad
456 powershell
```

Next, fill your listview

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $processes.Count; $i++) {
    $lvi = [System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]::new()
    $lvi.Text = $processes[$i].Name
    $lvi.SubItems.Add($processes[$i].Id)
    $ListviewOCLRA.Items.Add($lvi)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. This is how u explain to a newbie :)